# How do I dynamically change google recaptcha language using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I am using [react-google-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha).

I want to dynamically change the recaptcha element whenever I load this component.

Requirements:
1. Had to take new props and change the language
2. On unmount and remount the component should also render new language

- cleared the global values for google recaptcha on unmount.
- Forced recaptcha to remount whenever props change
- Combination of these two

`window.recaptchaOptions = { removeOnUnmount: true }` does not properly remove the recaptcha.

Expected: The recaptcha will remount and change it's language to the selected language.

Actual: Recaptcha will remount using the same language.

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of late to this question but since this morning I've been searching an answer to find a solution to do this with react hooks and without interfering with "window". I change the key of the component to cause a destroy and re-trigger which works for me:

```
const [recaptchaKey, setRecaptchaKey] = useState(0); // Change this key to trigger re-render

useEffect(() => {
    setCaptchaLanguage(i18n.language);
    setRecaptchaKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1);
    captchaRef.current.reset();
  }, [i18n.language]);

<ReCAPTCHA
     key={recaptchaKey}
     ref={captchaRef}
     sitekey={siteKey}
     onChange={onSuccessReCAPTCHA}
     onExpired={onFailReCAPTCHA}
     onErrored={onFailReCAPTCHA}
     hl={captchaLanguage}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. On mount dynamically import react-google-recaptcha
2. on unMount delete window.grecaptcha & window.recaptchaOptions
3. on update combine step 1 & 2

```js
export default class ReCaptchaValidation extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    handleChange: null,
    lang: 'en'
  }

  state = {
    Recaptcha: null
  }

  componentDidMount (): void {
    this.importRecaptcha()
  }

  importRecaptcha = async () => {
    const { lang } = this.props
    this.setState({ Recaptcha: null })
    delete window.recaptchaOptions
    delete window.grecaptcha
    window.recaptchaOptions = {
      lang,
      useRecaptchaNet: false,
      removeOnUnmount: false
    }
    const { default: Recaptcha } = await import('react-google-recaptcha')
    this.setState({ Recaptcha })
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    delete window.recaptchaOptions
    delete window.grecaptcha
  }

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps: Readonly<P>): void {
    if (prevProps.lang !== this.props.lang) {
      this.importRecaptcha()
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { apiKey, className, handleChange, lang } = this.props
    const { Recaptcha } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        {Recaptcha && (
          <Recaptcha
            sitekey={apiKey}
            size={'normal'}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```